# Joomla plugin allowing user to sign for articles updates

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'm looking for Joomla's plugin allowing user to sign for page updates (articles/forums etc)

Would be great if this can be integrated with joomla's user profile (kind of checkbox determining if user shall be notified content changes)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm well I just searched extensions and found some likely help.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-submission/15551